# Unable to select date in "https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form" using C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am unable to select a date in practice form when I supplied the date it just appends in it although I have used the `clear()` command as well. I am new to C# and selenium.

Below is the code:

```
IWebElement calndr = driver.FindElement(By.Id("dateOfBirthInput"));
calndr.Clear();
calndr.SendKeys("08 April 2023");
calndr.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: Actually, I haven't found a solution to that problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not select date on that calendar by inserting the date as a sting there.
You have to open the calendar and then to select the year and the month with the use of `Select` Selenium object and select the date. You also should use Expected Conditions explicit waits there.
This should work:

```cs
using DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
var open_calendar = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("dateOfBirthInput")));
open_calendar.Click();
var selectYear = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("react-datepicker__year-select")));
selectYear.SelectByValue("2023"); 
Thread.Sleep(400);
var selectMonth = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("react-datepicker__month-select")));
selectYear.SelectByValue("3"); 
Thread.Sleep(400);
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Xpath("//div[contains(@class,'react-datepicker__day--008') and (not(contains(@class,'outside')))]"))).Click();
```

I know, it's not recommended to use hardcoded pauses but without them it will not work, this web page needs pauses between actions.

Comment: thanks for the solution but it's not working, It is just clicking on the calendar field.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used and works good for me.

```
//Initiate Driver instance and go to url
            IWebDriver driver = InitBrowser("chrome");
            driver.Url = "https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form";

//Select DOB field then select date of month dropdown and assign to variable then select month by index
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("dateOfBirthInput")).Click();
            SelectElement MonthSelect = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("react-datepicker__month-select")));
            MonthSelect.SelectByIndex(3);

//Select year and assign to variable, then select year by index
            SelectElement YearSelect = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("react-datepicker__year-select")));
            YearSelect.SelectByIndex(123);

//Select the specific day you want by classname
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("react-datepicker__day--008")).Click();
```

All the class names were gotten from the html on the page. There should be no waits/thread.sleeps needed. Hope this works for you!